# Is the ally hero that I can use during a battle the strongest of my ally's heroes?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

Before a battle starts, during the hero selection, I can choose one of my allie's strong heroes to help me during the battle.

But is it always the strongest one ? How does it work ?